# Programmatically add rule to AVG Firewall

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I use AVG and have noticed when installing programs requiring internet access they frequently appear to add a 'Trusted Rule' to AVG's firewall giving them appropriate internet access rights. Does anyone have any idea how this is achieved?

Comment: What's the point of a firewall if any arbitrary program can add rules at will?

Comment: AVG probably has a hook to be called when processes are launched. It can then examine said processes and create rules accordingly. Without an API for a third party to control it, it's all up to AVG.

Comment: @GregHewgill It's to allow an automatic control so that the user does not have to be burdened with creating a new rule every time he installs a new networked program or updates one (not every user is savvy enough to know what a "firewall" even is, let alone customizing it).

Comment: @GregHewgill However it's done it will need Administrator privileges because your installing a program. AVG tells the user that it has added the rule because you trusted the installer to install the program in the first place. Frankly you would be better asking what's the use of any software based firewall but I'm pretty sure you have one running right now :-)

Comment: Cool.. so now all a bad-guy app needs to do is wrap itsself in an msi file.  Brillant.

Comment: @Boo I'm not to sure it's as easy as all that. I assume AVG (and all the rest of them) actually scan the program as well so Trojans etc will be detected. If AVG considers it safe then why not update it's own Firewall if the end user has already decided it's safe to install. I know it initially sounds scarey but when you think about it there's probably much less risk than one might first think.

Comment: ok.  so why bother with a firewall at all?  Sounds like you are saying that the virus scanner is good enough.  What you are proposing negates the firewall.  So why would a user even both with both?

Comment: @Boo I'm a developer, not a virus expert. My program needs internet access - I want to cut down on my Support calls. You ever done Support Calls. First question - Do you have a firewall. First answer, What's a firewall. Just answer the friggin questions please - Yes/No grrrrr :-(

Comment: I am not the AVG help-desk.  Perhaps you would get a response more to your liking from them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FirewallInstallHelper.dll` in a installation process (MSI, Wise, or other) to change firewall rules. Just notice that most firewall software still ask permission from the user.

This is what we used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417690(v=vs.85).aspx#Integrating_into_Windows_Installer

Comment: Actually, the Windows Firewall is easy to add an exception to. I use InstallAware and check if XP or Vista/Win7 and then just make execute netsh commands to add my programs. It's AVG I am/was having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Having waited a couple of weeks, AVG Support did finally get back to me. You need to send them your program (or at least a link) for them to 'test' it. If OK, they will then add it to their Trusted Programs database.